# PKCS7_Sign does not sign

Tags: openssl, sign, pkcs#7

here is part of code:

```
flags = 0;
flags |= PKCS7_BINARY;
flags |= PKCS7_NOATTR;
pkcs7 = PKCS7_sign( cert, pkey, NULL, bio_data, flags );
if ( !pkcs7 )
    return;

iErr = i2d_PKCS7_bio( bio_out_der, pkcs7 );
if ( iErr != 1 )
    return;
```

There are no errors when running, but i do not understand why output data does not contain sign. Output data is correct PKCS7 signedData structure, but it has prepared for singing data instead of sign itself. This is example of data which is in the end of output PKCS7 structure:

```
04400001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF003021300906052B0E03021A0500041440BD001563085FC35165329EA1FF5C5ECBDBBEEF
```

i.e. this is OID of SHA1, SHA1 of data to be signed, padding, i.e. data which must be signed with private key. Why signing is not performed?

Comment: Run PKCS7_verify on this data and check what it says. This will give you signed Data as per PKCS #7 standard. If you need signature explicitly, rather use RSA_sign or DSA_sign.

Comment: Perhaps you could show a minimum test case? It looks like you're doing the right thing as far as the docs are concerned; the only explanation I can think of is that `e=1` (which hopefully isn't the case!).